# Rails display progress bar while running query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a couple of MySQL queries that take a really long time and I'd like to display a progress bar while they are running. Is this possible in Rails with maybe jquery? Does ActiveRecord have any mechanisms for this?

Really? No ideas? Then how about this:

I have the queries separated by line,(connection.execute) can I call something that would resemble a progress bar between query calls?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem.
Make a wrapper for execute query, for example:

```
def execute_sql(sql_string)
  results = []
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    sql_string.split(';').each do |sql_query|
      if sql_query.present?
        result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_query)
        results << result if result
        your_progress = results.length
      end
    end
  end
end
```